# I want to use an online website using my vb.net application

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I have an application which deals with the website [flipcss.com](http://flipcss.com/).

For the "Or Paste CSS:" text I add text with the element id

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("css_data").InnerText = TextBox1.Text
```

And to click the "Flip the CSS" button I use the code

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```

But for the results or "generated" text, I cannot get it back to my application because it doesn't have an id.

The HTML inspector only has

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="css_data" rows="10" dir="LTR">
```

I want to bring the generated text back to another text box.

Comment: Try to use webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")

Comment: not working, error
"Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection' cannot be converted to 'String'
"

Comment: and also i want to get the text from the class which have only the (dir="LTR") string

Answer (score 0):

after some searching and editing i found it

```
For Each h As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
            If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(h.GetAttribute("dir"), Nothing) AndAlso h.GetAttribute("dir").Equals("LTR") Then
                TextBox2.Text = h.InnerText
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```